# delay in provider getting value from stream

Tags: firebase, flutter, google-cloud-firestore, provider

I'm building a multiple role based authentication app using flutter and firebase. I'm using provider to retrieve the users `uid` incase user is logged in or else it returns `null`.
Since I have to integrate multiple roles to each users, I have implemented this class which gets the Role field data from firestore of the current user's document and returns the screen based on the role.
It does the job well, I know its nowhere elegant, but it's been working fine.

```
class RoleCheck extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _RoleCheckState createState() => _RoleCheckState();
}
class _RoleCheckState extends State<RoleCheck> {
  String role;
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    final user = Provider.of<UserModel>(context);  
    if (user != null) {
      FirebaseFirestore.instance
          .collection('users')
          .doc(user.uid)
          .get()
          .then((docs) {
        if (docs.exists && docs.data().isNotEmpty) {
          setState(() {
            role = docs.data()['Role'];
          });
        }
      });
      if (role == 'student') {
        return StudentNavigationScreen();
      } else if (role == 'teacher') {
        return TeacherNavigationScreen();
      } else if (role == 'admin') {
        return AdminNavigationScreen();
      } else if (role == 'parent') {
        return ParentNavigationScreen();
      }
     
    }
     return Body();
  }
}
```

One issue is that even if a user has logged in, and I close and open up the app, it shows the login and signup screen ie `Body()` for a few seconds and then it shows the homescreen of the current user.
I want to prevent this Body from showing each time the user closes the app and I would like to improve or externalize the `Role checking` function.

this is my stream

```
 Stream<UserModel> get user {
    return _auth.authStateChanges().map(_userFromFirebaseUser);
  }

 UserModel _userFromFirebaseUser(User user) {
    return user != null ? UserModel(uid: user.uid) : null;
  }
```

this is the UserModel class

```
class UserModel {
  final String uid;

  UserModel({this.uid});
}
```

Answer (score 0):

`authStateChanges()` does not immediately give you a user object.  It takes some time for the SDK to load and validate the user token before it will deliver a user object for a user that was previously signed in.  You will have to write some code to show a wait screen or something similar if you want to improve the user experience while the user token is being loaded.